How to create a "Pay with PayPal" button on a website?
I have a site with PayPal buttons that look like this:

These buttons work, but I want the text to read "Pay with PayPal" instead of "Add to Cart".
Here's an example of what I've tried:
<p><font size="4" color="#000000">3 day pass to Mr. Scanner databases  $15.00</font></p>

<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="-----BEGIN PKCS7----- ... -----END PKCS7-----">

<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="3-day pass to Mr. Scanner databases">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="15.00">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="user@example.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://www.example.com/return.html">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="https://www.example.com/cancel.html">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<font size="+1" color="#000000">Pay with PayPal</font>
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/meips/ADKq_Nbu_wXklAgbf2tK67qncQ3hnxsK45vyao0CMWM5FXflTbz3Lq3tgSK3Ls2ZmHRiiTuRJzquOKK71GSof0TsrdDQzXCQJEX29E8=s0-d-e1-ft#https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>


inputs dont have a source. input type="image" as a Pay with PayPal button? There other things that should be fixed first and then you should start to read the PayPal documentation for their API.

How would I fix it?

The <font> element has been obsolete for about 25 years.

The best experience will be to use the new "Pay link or button" generator at www.paypal.com/buttons .  Use the account that is going to receive payments to generate the buttons.
At the bottom under "Change the look and feel", set "Pick what your button should say" to: Pay
Make sure the product name and price are correct, then click Build It and switch to the Button Code tab and copy the HTML.
Now for the tricky part, the first button you create will work as-is. Paste it into the website and test it. This should be the first/topmost button on the page.
For the second button and beyond you will need to remove this line:
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&components=hosted-buttons&enable-funding=venmo&currency=USD">

That script should only be loaded once per page; only the first button's should be kept.
You can further customize it on the first button by removing the &enable-funding=venmo and adding &disable-funding=venmo,paylater,card
